# Can I use dynamicHelpers (expressjs) with extend parameters?

Tags: node.js, express

(How) can I use dynamicHelpers with extend parameters like this?

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
    getImageUrl: function (req, res, imageName) {
        return "http://" + req.headers.host + app.set("imageUrl")+"/" + imageName;
    }
});
```

how can I call this from my template engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return a function from your function:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
    getImageUrl: function (req, res) {
        return function(imageName) {
            return "http://" + req.headers.host + app.set("imageUrl") + "/" + imageName;
        }
    }
});
```

In your template, you use `getImageUrl("some image.jpg")`.